# How can i make a clean url and hide url segment using htaccess in codeigniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

My URL looks like this:

```
http://kanchannews.com/news/news-details/103/Top-5-Mind-Blowing-Facts-You-Know-
About-Samsung
```

What i want to show is like:

```
http://kanchannews.com/news/Top-5-Mind-Blowing-Facts-You-Know-About-Samsung
```

Can I get this kind of url using htaccess? I'm using codeigniter for this projects.

Comment: You could probably make your own or download a project from GIThub. Such as: http://www.murrion.com/2011/08/how-to-build-your-own-url-shortener-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be done, with CI Routes. The problem you'll have is not having the ID of the post in your URL. If the title is also unique, you'll be fine.

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/news_by_title/$1';
```

This will re-route everything to a "news_by_title" method within your news controller, which you'll need to query the database using the title.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html